# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static-methods

Building a multi-language application in Java. Getting an error when inserting String value from `R.string` resource XML file:

```
public static final String TTT =  (String) getText(R.string.TTT);
```

This is the error message:

> Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getText(int) from the type 
>        Context

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you need it to be static for a 'multi language application'? Don't really understand.

Comment: Never store string resources in static data members. Always request them via `getString()` when you need them. That way, your application properly adjusts to users changing their chosen language.

Comment: [Fundamental Java :: Learning Trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Since `getText()` is non-static you cannot call it from a static method.

To understand why, you have to understand the difference between the two.

Instance (non-static) methods work on objects that are of a particular type (the class). These are created with the new like this:

```
SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass();
```

To call an instance method, you call it on the instance (`myObject`):

```
myObject.getText(...)
```

<s>However a static method/field can be called **only** on the type directly, say like this:</s>
*The previous statement is not correct. [One can also refer to static fields with an object reference like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) `myObject.staticMethod()` but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class variables.*

```
... = SomeClass.final
```

And the two cannot work together as they operate on different data spaces (instance data and class data)

Let me try and explain. Consider this class (psuedocode):

```
class Test {
     string somedata = "99";
     string getText() { return somedata; } 
     static string TTT = "0";
}
```

Now I have the following use case:

```
Test item1 = new Test();
 item1.somedata = "200";

 Test item2 = new Test();

 Test.TTT = "1";
```

What are the values?

Well

```
in item1 TTT = 1 and somedata = 200
in item2 TTT = 1 and somedata = 99
```

In other words, `TTT` is a datum that is shared by all the instances of the type. So it make no sense to say

```
class Test {
         string somedata = "99";
         string getText() { return somedata; } 
  static string TTT = getText(); // error there is is no somedata at this point 
}
```

**So the question is why is *TTT* static or why is getText() not static?**

Remove the `static` and it should get past this error - but without understanding what your type does it's only a sticking plaster till the next error. What are the requirements of `getText()` that require it to be non-static?

Comment: it static because  i call it from several files in my project.
when i removed the "static" the error code is gone, but now i have lots of errors in other files that using this variable.

Comment: But that is my point. You need to understand when the two can be used.

Comment: when i add the line "Constants notifications_values = new Constants(); to my main activity class, it compile OK but in the emulator it crash when this activity run

Answer (score 13):

There are some good answers already with explanations of why the mixture of the non-static `Context` method `getText()` can't be used with your `static final String`.

A good question to ask is:  why do you want to do this?  You are attempting to load a `String` from your `strings` resource, and populate its value into a `public static` field.  I assume that this is so that some of your other classes can access it?  If so, there is no need to do this.  Instead pass a `Context` into your other classes and call `context.getText(R.string.TTT)` from within them.

```
public class NonActivity {

    public static void doStuff(Context context) {
        String TTT = context.getText(R.string.TTT);
        ...
    }
}
```

And to call this from your `Activity`:

```
NonActivity.doStuff(this);
```

This will allow you to access your `String` resource without needing to use a `public static` field.

Comment: thank you very much, i changed all of files according to your recommendation.

Comment: I was trying to do this, but for a string-array, and with `String a[] = context.getTextArray(R.array.myStringArray);`  ; it, however, gives me an error `The method getTextArray(int) is undefined for the type 
 Context` -- why would it be undefined whereas it works with getText?

Comment: @auspicious99 simply because a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) does not have a method called `getTextArray`, but does have `getText`. Perhaps you are thinking of [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) which does have `getTextArray`

Answer (score 10):

for others that find this in the search:

I often get this one when I accidentally call a function using the class name rather than the object name. This typically happens because i give them too similar names : P

ie:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

// then later

MyClass.someFunction();
```

This is obviously a static method. (good for somethings)
But what i really wanted to do (in most cases was)

```
myclass.someFunction();
```

It's such a silly mistake, but every couple of months, i waste about 30 mins messing with vars in the "MyClass" definitions to work out what im doing wrong when really, its just a typo.

Funny note: stack overflow highlights the syntax to make the mistake really obvious here.

Comment: Doesn't your IDE highlight this too? I guess you can configure it to do so :)

Comment: this saved me a few hours of my time, THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

You can either make your variable non static

```
public final String TTT =  (String) getText(R.string.TTT);
```

or make the "getText" method static (if at all possible)

Answer (score 2):

getText is a member of the your Activity so it must be called when "this" exists. Your static variable is initialized when your class is loaded before your Activity is created.

Since you want the variable to be initialized from a Resource string then it cannot be static. If you want it to be static you can initialize it with the String value.

Answer (score 2):

You can not make reference to static variable from non-static method.
To understand this , you need to understand the difference between static and non-static.

Static variables are class variables , they belong to class with their only one instance , created at the first only.
Non-static  variables are initialized every time you create an object of the class.

Now coming to your question, when you use new() operator we will create copy of every non-static filed for every object, but it is not the case for static fields. That's why it gives compile time error if you are referencing a static variable from non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not new and existing answers give some good theoretical background. I just want to add a more pragmatic answer.

getText is a method of the Context abstract class and in order to call it, one needs an instance of its subclass (Activity, Service, Application or other). The problem is, that the public static final variables are initialized before any instance of Context is created.

There are several ways to solve this:

1. Make the variable a member variable (field) of the Activity or other subclass of Context by removing the static modifier and placing it within the class body;
2. Keep it static and delay the initialization to a later point (e.g. in the onCreate method);
3. Make it a local variable in the place of actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can make call on non-static method into static method because we need to remember first' we can create an object that's class we can call easyly on non -static method into  static mathod