# How do update the calendar dynamically from my Android code

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to be able to create an event in the Google Calendar from my Android app. I believe there is a Calendar API but I have never used it. I'm fairly new to Android development so I've found a few examples from browsing earlier and used the following code to try to update my Android Calendar.

```
public static boolean updateCalendar(Context context,String cal_Id,String eventId)
{
try{

    Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse(CAL_URI+"events");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CALENDAR_URI, null, null, null, null);
    String[] s = c.getColumnNames();

    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
            while (c.moveToNext())
        {

            String _id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String CalId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("calendar_id"));            
            if ((_id==null) && (CalId == null))
            {
                             return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_id.equals(eventId) && CalId.equals(cal_Id))
                             {
                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI, Integer.parseInt(_id));
                    context.getContentResolver().update(uri, null, null, null);// need to give your data here
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
finally
{
    return true;
}
}
```

However when I run it the getColumnNames doesn't get called and the code jumps straight to the line context.getContentResolver().update(uri, null, null, null); and then exits.

I put a couple of test events in my Calendar, why is the code not picking them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to add event to calender to particular date and time

```
Uri event1;
    long epoch;
    long epoch1;


Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                try 
                {
                    epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(YourStartDate+" "+YourStratTime).getTime();
                    //epoch=epoch;
                    Log.e("epoch",String.valueOf(epoch));
                    epoch1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(YourStartDate+" "+YourEndDate).getTime();
                    //epoch1=epoch1;
                    Log.e("epoch1",String.valueOf(epoch1));
                } catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                values.put("calendar_id", 1);
                values.put("title", "Appoitment");
                values.put("allDay", 0);
                values.put("dtstart",epoch); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
                values.put("dtend", epoch1 ); // ends 60 minutes from now
                values.put("description", "Your consulting date and time ");
                values.put("visibility", 0);
                values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                if(EVENTS_URI!=null)
                {
                event1 = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
                }

                // reminder insert
                Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
                values = new ContentValues();
                values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event1.getLastPathSegment()));
                values.put( "method", 1 );
                values.put( "minutes", 10 );
                if(REMINDERS_URI!=null)
                {   
                cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
                }
```

getCalendarUroBase function:

```
private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {

                String calendarUriBase = null;
                Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
                Cursor managedCursor = null;
                try {
                    managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (managedCursor != null) {
                    calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
                } else {
                    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
                    try {
                        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (managedCursor != null) {
                        calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
                    }
                }
                return calendarUriBase;
            }
```

Note: As per Sample Date should be in yyyy-MM-dd, time should be in hh:mm formats

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've embedded the code into my application but I'm getting a couple of error messages. The two lines of code      Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();                        Are throwing error messages, the first says 'You cannot use this in a static context' and the second says 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContentResolver() from the type ContextWrapper'.

Comment: may you have placed the code in static method check it once, may not work in emulator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method check this

Comment: Thanks Abhi that was the problem. I've run the code now and when it gets to the line event1 = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
, I get an error 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL nullevents' have I missed anything?

Comment: did you add these permissions  <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR">
  </uses-permission>
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR">
   </uses-permission>

Comment: Thanks Abhi, I've added the permissions and that works fine now.