# Java: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method createImage(int, int) from the type Component

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

I am trying to tile a background, but now I am stuck. I have read the documentation for `createImage()`, but for some reason something is static, and I can't figure out how or why.

Here is the code I have:

```
Paint paint;

    if (paint == null) {
        try {
            // Create TexturePaint instance the first time
            Component c;

            Image image = c.getToolkit().getImage("Background.png");

            int height = image.getHeight(null);
            int width = image.getWidth(null);

            BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) Component.createImage(width, height);
            Graphics2D biG2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();

            biG2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, Color.black, null);

            paint = new TexturePaint(bi, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I couldn't find a single answer on the internet, so I don't know what's going wrong. :(

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method

Comment: I'm just going to have to find a different way to tile a background. This way is turning out to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems createImage is not a static method, so you can't directly access that method using class name.

`createImage` is instance method, so you need to instantiate `Component` and call `createImage` from that instance.

Example:

```
Component comp = new Component(..);
comp.createImage(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) Component.createImage(width, height);
```

is incorrect. You are making a static call on the `Component` class that does not exist. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, given that you have a `Component` instance declared, but not initialized, higher up in your code. If you did this:

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) c.createImage(width, height);
```

You would no longer get the compiler warning, but running the code would net you an NPE. You might want to better define what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But if I remove it, I get this error: `The method createImage(int, int) is undefined for the type DisplayMap`

Comment: I am not sure what your outer class is, since you didn't post it in the code sample. But you have to make the `createImage` call on a properly initialized subclass of `Component`. Where is the `c` variable initialized, in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which invokes the method on your *instance* of `Component`:

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) c.createImage(width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably instead of this line

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) Component.createImage(width, height);
```

you should use your Component object, c, instead:

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) c.createImage(width, height);
```

However, I don't see how c is going to be anything other than null with the code as it currently stands.  But perhaps that is a separate problem that you will be able to address yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're going to set this `TexturePaint` object as the `Paint` attribute of a `Graphics2D` object that you obtained from a `Component`. You will need to create your `BufferedImage` using the same component.