# Java Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, static

I'm writing an Android app and am getting this error, but I'm not sure why. Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error?

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method updateScores(List<Score>) from the type DatabaseHandler
```

Here's the relevant code.

```
public class ScoreList extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    List<Score> listScore = new ArrayList<Score>();
    public void updateListView() {
        listViewScore.setAdapter(new ScoreListAdapter(ctx,
                R.layout.score_row_item, listScore));
        DatabaseHandler.updateScores(listScore);    
    }
}
```

Here's the DatabaseHandler class. I tried making the function static, but it won't work that way due to errors.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scoreKeeper";
    private static final String TABLE_GAMES = "games";    
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CHANGE = "scoreChange";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL = "scoreTotal";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_GAMES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GAMES + "("
                + KEY_NAME + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_CHANGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TOTAL + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_GAMES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GAMES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();    
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, score.getName()); 
        values.put(KEY_CHANGE, score.getScoreChange());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL, score.getScoreTotal());       

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_GAMES, null, values);
        db.close(); 
    }

    public List<Score> getAllScores() {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_GAMES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score("","","");
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setScoreChange(cursor.getString(1));
                score.setScoreTotal(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return scoreList;       
    }

    public void updateScores(List<Score> score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GAMES);
        onCreate(db);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for(int i = 0; i < score.size(); i++){
            values.put(KEY_NAME, score.get(i).getName());
            values.put(KEY_CHANGE, score.get(i).getScoreChange());     
            values.put(KEY_TOTAL, score.get(i).getScoreTotal());    
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Make Static Reference to Non-Static Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are accessing the method  with static reference

```
DatabaseHandler.updateScores(listScore);
```

means with class name..

You have to make a instance of `DatabaseHandler` class and use that method.

Or make a `updateScores` as static method like,

```
static public void updateScores()
```

But I have a doubt you have more codes in `DatabaseHandler` Class. (As its sqlite database helper class you are using Activity context in this class) so better to make **instance** of `DatabaseHandler` class and use method `updateScores()` with instance.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the first one? I had already tried making the method static and as you guessed, I have other code that stops working when I do it.

Comment: Ok, In your application activity 's on `create()` write `DatabaseHandler dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);`  And in `updateListView()` just write `dbHelper.updateScores(listScore);` Make sure `DatabaseHandler dbHelper` is a global variable in `ScoreList`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void updateScores(List<Score> score)
```

change to

```
public static void updateScores(List<Score> score)
```

Why?

Because you are using **static** call

```
DatabaseHandler.updateScores(listScore)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method `updateScores` to `static` as below:

```
 public static void updateScores(List<Score> score)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler();
dbh.updateScores(listScore);
```

Comment: Did this and get "The constructor DatabaseHandler() is undefined"

Comment: You updated your code after my post. So you have parameterized constructor in your DatabaseHandler. So better make updateScores as static method

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the Method

> public void updateScores(List score)

as **static** or you can make an object of `**DatabaseHandler **` in the caller class:

> ScoreList

Answer (score 1):

Error message tell you exectly problem: you reference non-static method in static manner.
There are two possibilities:
1. You want have static method (see other answers)
2. You want have non-static method. Then use this caller snippet:

```
DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler();
helper.updateScores(listScore);
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is because of you are calling the non static method using class name .to overcome this error you have to do the any one of the following things 
1 . make your method updateScores as static or
2 . create an instance of DatabaseHandler and call using that object call the method.

calling method using class name requires method to be a static