# cannot make static reference error in line 42

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The code is to get contacts list. But for one error. Pleas help me resolve. 
The mContext on line 42 returns and error "cannot make a **static reference to the non-static** method `getapplicationcontext()` from the type contextwrapper".

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;
Context mContext =  getApplicationContext();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();
    data();
    getVcardString();
}
public static void getVcardString() {   


    String path = null;     
    String vfile = null;; 
     vfile = "Contacts.vcf"; 

    Cursor phones =              mContext.getContentResolver(). query(ContactsContract.     CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

    phones.moveToFirst();
    Log.i("Number of contacts", "cursorCount" +phones.getCount());  
    for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)   {       

         String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
         Log.i("lookupKey", " " +lookupKey);
         Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
         AssetFileDescriptor fd;

         try  {
             fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
             FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
             byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
             fis.read(buf);
             String VCard = new String(buf);          

             path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +    File.separator + vfile;
             FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
             mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());    

             phones.moveToNext();               

             File filevcf = new File(path);
             Log.i("file", "file" +filevcf);

         }catch(Exception e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();  
         }
    }       
    Log.i("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");          
}

protected void data() {             
    File filelocation = filevcf ;     
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
    sharingIntent.setType("application/x-vcard");       
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "mail@gmail.com" );       sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));            
 }  

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context =   getApplicationContext();


    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, secondjav.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);   


        }

    });

  }

}
```

Comment: remove the static for the method

Comment: remove `static` from  `public static void getVcardString(){.......}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744746/java-error-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

This error means you are trying to access `mContext`, which is an instance field, in `getVcardString()`, which is a static method (thus NOT depending on an instance).

*Note: As pointed out by @KiKMak42, I'm assuming here that the error you get is for* `mContext` *now, and not the* `getApplicationContext()` *method anymore.*

#### Solution

You can do one of these 2 things:

- Make this method non-static by removing the `static` keyword. If you do this, then an instance of this class will be needed to call this method, so `mContext` will exist.
- Add the context as a parameter of the method (and do not reference the instance field `mContext` anymore)

To complete the answer, in any other context (no pun intended) you could technically also make the `mContext` field static (depending on the use you have of it). However, it's rarely the best option, and you **clearly DON'T want to do that** here. And you'll never want to do that for any `Context` in Android.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the error, it says cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getapplicationcontext().

Comment: Line 42 is that `mContext`, the wording of the error is weird indeed, but this reference will break anyway at this point. The OP probably used to get the error you mention, copy-pasted the error message, then moved the method reference to `mContext`'s initialization. Which will cause another error message, which I'm  replying to.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need that your method "getVcardString()" remains static, then you should do something like this:
create new class for your application that extend android.app.Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   static Context appContext;

   public MyApplication() {
       super();
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();   

      appContext = getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getContext() {
       return appContext;
   }
}
```

add this attribute in your manifest to application tag:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

and in your getVcardString() method instead use of mContext use this static method of MyApplication Class:

```
MyApplication.getContext()
```

by this way you make application context accessible every where in your application.

Answer (score -2):

Remove `final` from

```
final Context context =   getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Removing `final` just allows to modify `context`'s value, it does not allow static references.