# Android - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field

Tags: java, android, string, static

The string title cannot be static because of the intent.. The string URL has to be static for the usage of it.. This means i get the error when i try to add a non-static string to a static string. how can i make it work?

Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field title

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String title = i.getStringExtra("title");


static final String URL = "http://csddata.site11.com/dynamic.php?cat=" + title;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to make `URL` static? If you do not make it static it should work.

Comment: This question was already [answered elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do need to keep your string static and final you could do

```
static final String URL = "http://csddata.site11.com/dynamic.php?cat=%s";

Intent i = getIntent();
String title = i.getStringExtra("title");

String finalUrl = String.format(URL,title);
```

Answer (score 1):

This wont work because you will be getting value of `title` when the present activity is launched.

The String URL is  static & final. Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution . These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables.
Declaring the field as 'final' will ensure that the field is a constant and cannot change.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String title = i.getStringExtra("title");


String URL = "http://csddata.site11.com/dynamic.php?cat=" + title;
```

Your code must fine now!!

Comment: The String URL needs to be Static Final.

Comment: ur getting tile from another activity at runtime, so this is impossible to obtain if String is static & final