# Java Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method in a single class with multiple methods

Tags: java

I have single class in java having two methods. one is public static void main(String args []).
when i call other method inside main i get above error.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method();
    }

    private void method() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static

Comment: This question was [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method?rq=1) multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

When this is unclear, you should follow some basic java tutorials first.
This is a nice start: [What is the best java tutorial site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3120324/1183010).

Answer (score 1):

Solution - make the other method static as well - **OR** make an instance to it through the class Test (using the **new** operator)

ALTERNATIVE 1 (using static)

```
 class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    method();
 }

 private static void method() {
    System.out.println("hello");
 }

}
```

---

ALTERNATIVE 2 (using an instance of the class Test)

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.method();
 }

 private void method() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of `Test`, because non static methods should be called from instance:

```
new Test().method();
```