# Tried to call method from another class get an error instead. JAVA

Tags: java

Hi I'm pretty sure this is a beginner JAVA question. I ran my compiler and it showed that there is an error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method roll() from the type Die
```

on the last line of my main method.

What I am trying to do is roll two dices and add them up. My question is what is wrong with this line
and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance

```
       /** main method

       Die myDie1 = new Die();
       Die myDie2 = new Die();



      for(int roll=1;roll<=total;roll++)
          {
              counts[(Die.roll()+Die.roll())]++; //<--error here
          } 
       **/
```

Dice method

```
   public class Die
     {
       private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

       private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        public Die()
        {
         faceValue = 1;
         }

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       public int roll()
      {
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

        return faceValue;
      }

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Face value mutator.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        public void setFaceValue (int value)
       {
          faceValue = value;
       }

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Face value accessor.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        public int getFaceValue()
       {
           return faceValue;
         }

     //-----------------------------------------------------------------
     //  Returns a string representation of this die.
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public String toString()
    {
       String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

       return result;
     }
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Make Static Reference to Non-Static Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method)

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
counts[(Die.roll()+Die.roll())]++;
```

to

```
counts[myDie1.roll()+ myDie2.roll()]++;
```

Note there is a missing left parenthesis too

Comment: are you sure `missing left parenthesis` ?

Comment: just gave the duplicate answer.. you got it first :)

Comment: ah , there is isn't a missing parenthesis in the original post. Need to get my prescription glasses checked :)

Comment: @AiZhuXue please accept one of the answers if your problem has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of type `Die` or make your `method static`. Maybe you should have a look at static classes and variables as well as java objects and their differences.

One way is:

Change:

```
public int roll()
{
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

        return faceValue;
}
```

To:

```
public static int roll()
{
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

        return faceValue;
}
```

The better and Java OO way is to change from

```
for(int roll=1;roll<=total;roll++)
{
    counts[(Die.roll()+Die.roll())]++;
}
```

to:

```
for(int roll=1;roll<=total;roll++)
{
    counts[(myDie1.roll()+myDie2.roll())]++; 
}
```

Comment: there is a missing left parenthesis in the array index

Comment: There is no class of type `Roll`

Comment: @ScaryWombat good one, got confused with his code and variables name. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to replace:

```
counts[(Die.roll()+Die.roll())]++;
```

with:

```
counts[(myDie1.roll()+myDie2.roll())]++;
```

Call the instantiated methods on the objects, not the uninstantiated methods on the class

Answer (score 0):

That is because u giving Static method ref into the non static object.

according to the java u can not call method threw direct reference. so u need to make that method static.

so change your method according to this .

```
 public static int roll()
      {
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

        return faceValue;
      }
```

and after you update this this will work

```
for(int roll=1;roll<=total;roll++)
          {
              counts[(Die.roll()+Die.roll())]++; //<--error here will be solved
          }
```

hope this helps.