# Android - get edittext and store it to private variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

im new in this.
but i have private variable which is have static text

```
private static final String URL = "http://google.com";
```

.
and i create edittext like this

```
                android:id="@+id/url"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/add_url"
                android:inputType="textUri" />
```

how can i set the private variable from the edittext above?

is it

```
private static final String URL = urledittext.value;
```

? thats how done in pascal. because im new for java.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
private static final String URL = url.getText().toString();
```

Look that your `EditText` have the id `url`.

Of course, you have to reference your `EditText` before using the method `.getText()`:

```
EditText url = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
```

---

**EDIT:** You can have your `URL` variable created in the top of your Activity.

```
private static final String URL;
```

and in your onCreate() method use the code that I put above:

```
EditText url = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
URL = url.getText().toString();
```

Now the value of your `URL` variable will be the same as the text on the `EditText`.

Comment: maybe the mainactivity not recognize the url edit text field?

Comment: @MuliaRifaiAroyan Edited answer. You have to make reference to the `EditText` before using the method `.getText()`

Comment: i see, but the private static stuff is above the oncreate. how to reference the edittext so it can use for any java without reference again?

Comment: cannot make static reference to the non-static  field url

Comment: it say : The blank final field URL may not have been initialized

Comment: should i give you full source the activity?

Comment: @sailornoob If you provide some executable code I could prove it. It would be good.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6x7EacMA , please look at this code.  and i get the full source http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ios-android-retirement/

Comment: Try getText ().toString ();

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field url.

Comment: @sailornoob Look the answer that it is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method. I think it could help you a bit but it seems that you have to remove the static on your URL variable.