# Java static main also codingBat

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

```
public class CodingBat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumDouble(5,5));
    }

    public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
        if( a ==b) {
            return 2*a + 2* b;
        } else{
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

So I made this code, and I'm really confused why it doesn't work unless I write static between the public int sumDouble, because I was practicing on codingBat, and to answer the question they did not involve static, but then how do they test code. Do they use the main? I mean you have to to get the code running right?
So to my knowledge, static means that every object of this class will all contain the same value.But I don't see the relevance of this error.

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method"

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: **static** context, can't access **non-static** methods.

Comment: You cannot call a non static method from an static method.
When you want to call your method without the static modifier you need to create an instance of CodingBat: `new CodingBat().sumDouble(5, 5);`

Comment: So your question is, how do they test the code I write on a third-party website?

Comment: Why have you named `sumDouble` the method which sums *integers*?

Answer (score 1):

> and I'm really confused why it doesn't work unless I write static
>   between the public int sumDouble,

Yes, `static` is required

Since the `main method is static` and the `sumDouble() method is not`, you can't call the method without creating object of class. You cannot refer non-static members from a static method.

Either make method `static` or create object as below and then access method.

```
CodingBat obj = new CodingBat();
 System.out.println(obj.sumDouble(5,5));
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method) for more

Answer (score 0):

Either you call it through a static context, meaning like you do (or, from another class, by: `ClassName.methodName();` )

Or, you have to call it as an instance method, which it is, if you don't declare it static.Then, however, you'll need an instance to call it through:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        CodingBat cB = new CodingBat();
        System.out.println(cB.sumDouble(5,5));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object in order to use this method

```
public class CodingBat {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CodingBat obj = new CodingBat();
        System.out.println(obj.sumDouble(5,5));
    }
    public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
        if( a ==b){
            return 2*a + 2* b;}
        else{
            return a + b;}
    }
```

}