# How to change random number after the user has guessed it right and displays message when user has input a wrong data type

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm making a Random Number guessing app, but the app only works once, and you have to relaunch the app to play again, how do i make users to play again after they have guessed the right result by changing the random number again.
And also, i would like the app to detect if users had inputted a wrong number or strings inside the text field, how can i do that?
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

```
    int randomNumber;

public void output(View view)
{
    EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String guessedNumberString = guess.getText().toString();

    int guessedNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNumberString);

    String message = "";
    try {
        if (guessedNumberInt > randomNumber) {
            message = "Too high";
        } else if (guessedNumberInt < randomNumber) {
            message = "Too low";
        } else {
            message = "You are right! Try it again!";
        }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        message = "Enter a valid number";
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);
}
```

Comment: InputMismatchException is not what you think it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Make Static Reference to Non-Static Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the logic:

```
 if(input == randNum){


ReLaunchGame();

}
```

Now, for method `ReLaunchGame()` you must either restart the activity, or reset all the textfields.

Just compare their input with the random number you picked. Now, to see if they entered a wrong input. You must first understand exception handling, which I think you do.

[image]

(http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/)

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
try
{
  System.out.println("Please input an integer");
  //nextInt will throw InputMismatchException
  //if the next token does not match the Integer
  //regular expression, or is out of range
  int usrInput=sc.nextInt();
}
catch(InputMismatchException exception)
{
  //Print "This is not an integer"
  //when user put other than integer
  System.out.println("This is not an integer");
}
```

**Thats it.** Let me know if it worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways i know of:
1. create a startGame method to setup the game i.e. generate random and in your output method call it after user guessed it
2. use this to refresh whole activity finish(); startActivity(getIntent());

And for 2nd part play around with some if else before converting to integer

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user inputted a number, put the `parseInt()` line inside the `try` block.
The exception you have to catch here is `NumberFormatException`.
So it should look like this:

```
try {
    int guessedNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNumberString);
    ...
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    message = "Enter a valid number";
}
```

I am not familiar with Android, so I don't know when that `output()` function is called. However, you could try creating a flag before the `try` block to indicate if the user guessed the number correctly. Then, create another random number at the end of the function if the flag is `true`. You would also need to make the `randomGenerator` a class variable.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
public void output(View view)
{
    ...
    boolean correct = false;
    try {
        ...
        } else {
            message = "You are right! Try it again!";
            correct = true;
        }
    }
    ...
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (correct) {
        randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);
    }
}
```