# Use toString on array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
import java.io.*;

class Main0
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String onoma, epitheto, key01;
        short AriMit, EtosEis, AM, key02;
        int i, pos;
        Foititis pinakas[] = new Foititis(3);
        for (i = 0; i < pinakas.length; i++)
        {       
            System.out.println("Ola ta stoixeia na einai taksinomimena symfwna me ton Arithmo Mitroou." + "\n" + "Dwste Onoma.");
            do
            {
                onoma = FUserInput.getString();
                if (onoma == "x")
                    System.out.println("Mh egkyrh timh. Epanalagete");
            } while (onoma == "x");

            System.out.println("Dwste Epitheto.");
            do
            {
                epitheto = FUserInput.getString();
                if (epitheto == "x")
                    System.out.println("Mh egkyrh timh. Epanalagete");
            } while (epitheto == "x");

            System.out.println("Dwste Arithmo Mitrwou.");
            do
            {
                AriMit = FUserInput.getshort();
                if (AriMit == -1)
                    System.out.println("Mh egkyrh timh. Epanalagete");
            } while (AriMit == -1);

            System.out.println("Dwste Etos Eisagwghs.");
            do
            {
                EtosEis = FUserInput.getshort();
                if (EtosEis == -1)
                    System.out.println("Mh egkyrh timh. Epanalagete");
            } while (EtosEis == -1);

            pinakas[i] = new Foititis(onoma, epitheto, AriMit, EtosEis);
        }
        pos = 1;
        System.out.println(Foititis.toString(pos, pinakas));
    }
}

class Foititis      
{
    private String onoma, epitheto;
    private short AriMit, EtosEis;

    public Foititis (String on, String ep, short AM, short EE)
    {
        onoma = on;
        epitheto = ep;
        AriMit = AM;
        EtosEis = EE;
    }

    public String getEpwnymo()      //alles klaseis
    {
        return epitheto;
    }

    public String toString(int j, Foititis b[])
    {
        String emf;
        emf = b[j].onoma;
    }
}

class FUserInput        
 /*dedomenwn kateli3a na xrisimopoihsw thn "FUserInput" gia ola ta dedomena, anti na kanw "catch" to "exception" gia kathe scanner ksexwrista, kathws eixa skopo na xrisimopoihsw mono scanner)*/
{
    static String getString() 
    { 
        String line;
        InputStreamReader eisodosDouble = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(eisodosDouble);
        try
        {
            line = br.readLine();
            return line;
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {   
            return "x";
        }
    }

    static short getshort() 
    { 
        String line;
        InputStreamReader eisodosDouble = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(eisodosDouble);
        try
        {
            line = br.readLine();
            short i = Short.parseShort(line);
            return i;
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {   
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a duplicate of anything, I am not asking about my string equations but about the toString method that I want to use!!!!

So I have this code... all it does is to create an array of objects of type `Foititis`, named `pinakas` and having the four attributes. If you look at class named `Foititis` you will notice a `toString` method, all I want to do is to use the `toString` method to show something on the screen (at this example it is simplified to the `onoma` attribute of the array-object). Note that I also want to send the certain position of the array that I want to be seen(pos -> j), at this example the position is fixed (set to 1) but in the actual code it won't.

I try to compile it and I get these 2 errors, the second one is probably justified because I haven't written the code in the proper way, but what about the first? I have done the same thing again and I had no problem (at creating an array of objects).

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOpwr.jpg)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method

Comment: @MarounMaroun Even though his `== "x"` in his if's and while's should be replaced with `.equals("x")`, it isn't what he was asking in his question. In his error that he linked at the bottom he has a problem with his array (see answer below by @mikea), and he has a problem with a static call on a non-static method (the `System.out.println(Foititis.toString(pos, pinakas));` should be relaced with `System.out.println(pinakas[pos].toString());` and the `toString` method in `Foititis` should be replaced with `public String toString(){ return onoma; }`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you very much! IT WORKED! and

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare an array, so it should be:

```
Foititis pinakas[] = new Foititis[3];
```

Comment: Really? How did I miss that... Anyway thank you