# Arrays toString with objects that also have a toString method

Tags: java, arrays, output

I am having a problem regarding the printing of a special array:

I print an array of several objects with the `System.out.println(Arrays.toString());` but now the array is filled with objects, that possess a value as char and I want to print each char assigned to the object.
How can I do that in code?

To clarify, let the array be something specific like this:

```
Class[] objList = {new Class(1, 'X'), new Class(4, 'Y')};
```

Where I want to call the `objList[0].toString()` and then the `objList[1].toString()` method, getting an output looking like:

```
[X, Y]
```

I hope this question is clear enough and would be happy if anyone could help me, thanks!

**NOTE**: the mentioned Class with the toString() method is just implemented in the Class and is written as `System.out.print(destination);`
I tried the explanation here: [Use toString on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775211/use-tostring-on-array-of-objects), but apparently it did not work.

```
public String toString() {
  System.out.print(Arrays.toString(objList.toString()));
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Arrays.deepToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: @Maethor: Read the error; that takes an array, not a string.

Comment: I tried this and only got:
`The method deepToString(Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: `Arrays.deepToString()` takes the array as an argument. Hence, call it without the intermediate `toString()`: `Arrays.deepToString(objList)`.

Comment: I see, now I get the `'X'` printed in front of the array which besides that consists of nulls

Comment: You're returning `null` in `toString()`. Don't do any printing in the method; return the string that results from the `Arrays.deepToString` call.

Comment: Do not name custom types with the names of well-known standard types like `Class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `toString()` method is not supposed to print anything itself; instead, it should *return* a string which is a representation of the object. If your class's character is obtained through the `getChar()` method, you could implement its `toString()` method as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(getChar());
}
```

This will convert the character to a `String` and return it.

If you do that, the code

```
Class[] objList = new Class[] { new Class(1,'X'), new Class(2,'Y') };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objList));
```

should output `[X, Y]`.

(I recommend to rename your class `Class` to something else, because it clashes with Java's `Class<T>` class.)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! 
(and the "Class" was just an example, because I wanted to keep it shorter, in my program it has a different name ;)

Comment: Using such names in an example is a tad confusing.

Comment: I'll remember it for next time!