# I am trying to fetch data from database where date = jdatechooser:

Tags: java, sql, jcalendar

I have a table with a column datetime i want to retrieve data from database where date is specified in jdatechooser but em continously getting error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDate() from
>   the type JDateChooser

Here is the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Date date = JDateChooser.getDate();
                try{ 
                String query = " Select *from Transactions WHERE "+date+"=?  ";
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }catch (Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

Comment: Unrelated, but: that's the wrong way to use a `PreparedStatement`. The query should be `Select *from Transactions WHERE date_column = ?` then use `pst.setDate(date)` to pass the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible to have a window with lots of different `JDateChooser` controls on it.  So when you refer to one of them, you need to specify which one, rather than just calling it `JDateChooser`.

Somewhere in your class, you'll have a declaration something like

```
private JDateChooser theChooser;
```

where you declare a variable to refer to your `JDateChooser` - that is, you give it a name.  Now, you need to use the **EXACT SAME NAME** when you refer to your `JDateChooser` in your `actionPerformed` method.  For example

```
Date date = theChooser.getDate();
```

But don't write `theChooser` - write whatever name **YOU** gave the `JDateChooser` when you declared the variable.

Comment: I changed as you said to this: Date date = jDate.getDate(); but now getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ERROR ON THE SAME LINE