# sql query to get date from jdatechooser:

Tags: java, sql, jdatechooser, jcalendar

Help me: i am trying to populate data from sql database with the selected date from jdatechooser only i.e showing data from database of date 2017-08-30 only.

Here is the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    try
    { 
        Date date = jDate.getDate();
        String query = " Select *from Transactions WHERE Month(transaction_date) =  Month('"+date+"')  ";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        //pst.setDate(1,sqlchooser);             CONVERT(char(10), transaction_date  ,126)=CONVERT(char(10), getdate(),126);";
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch (Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I have updated code in question sir kindly review

Comment: what does `Month(transaction_date) '"+date+"'` mean? i don't any thing similair before

Comment: it will compar month part only check again i updated sorry previous one was not right

Comment: so what is the problem now?

Comment: Do you get any error on above code? please update that too, so we can find where you are facing problem.

Comment: it shows null pointer exception: error

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46292039/edit) your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46292039/230513) to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Please learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`