# SonarLint Squid:S1612 with AddActionListener on Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8, sonarlint, method-reference

First, all my **action listeners** call a private method in my class. They are in the `initComponents` method that is not static, and so are the private method called by the **action listeners**.

The project was on Java 1.5 and moved to Java 1.8. *SonarLint* didn't like those statements :

```
someButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    doSomeAction(evt);
  }
});
```

At first, *SonarLint* propose to change those assignment using lambdas (Squid:S1604).

I changed those with:

```
someButton.addActionListener(e -> doSomeAction(e));
```

Then the strange Squid:S1612 occured: it propose to use method references instead. Here is what I did:

```
someButton.addActionListener(ClassName::doSomeAction);
```

Then *Eclipse Oxygen* said that this is an error and won't compile The error message is:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method doSomeAction(ActionEvent) from the type ClassName
```

So the question is: can I really use method reference or should I just stick with lambda?

Comment: When `doSomeAction` is an instance method, you need `this::doSomeAction`.

Comment: I made some other changes since one other *SolarLint* warning said that the `ActionEvent` param wasn't used in the method `doSomeAction`. I removed them and now the Squid:S1612 disappeared since the method references needs a perfect match in the prototype (method signature). Just for fun, I tried your solution by adding back the param and it worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)