# How to use "pauseTimers"

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app for WebView in android, how i can stop the WebView with "onPause()" i have tried to use this code:

```
    @Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WebView.pauseTimers();
}
```

But it don't work, it says:

```
Error: non-static method pauseTimers() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

This is the all code of WebView

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.loadUrl("MyURL");

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on what you're trying to say? At the moment your question makes little sense. Include some relevant code if that helps. `public` and `private` only affect visibility of classes within your own app.

Comment: Hi, i have re-elaborated the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a non-static method in a static way. Firstly a quick explaination of what a `static` method does. Consider this class:

```
public class ClassA {
    public void methodOne() {}
    public static void methodTwo() {}
}
```

`methodOne` is an Instance method. This can only be called from an instance of `ClassA` declared with the `new` keyword, like so:

```
ClassA myClassA = new ClassA();
myClassA.methodOne();
```

`methodTwo` is `static`, therefore it belongs to the class itself, and not any particular instance of that class. The downside of this is that `static` methods cannot access member variables unless they too are declared `static`:

```
ClassA.methodTwo();
```

In your case, you need to call `pauseTimers()` on the **instance** of the `WebView` object you've declared in your Activity or layout. So from your code posted above:

```
private WebView myWebView; // Move this declaration out from onCreate()

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // rest of the method...
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myWebView.pauseTimers();
}
```

---

Comment: I've chosen to answer rather than raise a duplicate as I've already used up my flag for this question, before the extra information was provided. However, the relevant dupe would be this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method