# how does the method work without a keyword infront?

Tags: java, constructor

here is the sample code

```
public class BankAccount {
    protected double getBalance() {return 1000.0;}
    }
```

```
package test;

public class SavingAccount extends BankAccount{
    protected double getBalance() {return 1010.0;}
    protected void printBalance() {
    System.out.println(super.getBalance());
    System.out.println(getBalance());
    System.out.println(this.getBalance());
    }
}
```

Super.getBalance() returns the value of the parent class, so it is 1000.0
this.getBalace() returns the value of the current object, so it is 1010.0
but I am not sure how getBalance() works. shouldn't it be the same as this.getBalance()?
also how do I run it to see the result? I am using eclipse. Didn't find out how to run it without a main.  and can't just creat a main like

```
public void main (String[] args) {
        SavingAccount.printBalance();
    }
```

because "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method printBalance() from the type SavingAccount"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

`printBalance` is an instance method. You need to instantiate a `SavingAccount` object in order to call it. e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SavingAccount sa = new SavingAccout();
    sa.printBalance();
}
```